# Error:(83, 42) java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from float to int

Tags: java

while trying to paint Graphics i get the error below, my x and y are FLoat types.

```
 public void paint(Graphics g){
       for (int x = 0; x < lols.toArray().length-1; x++) {
          City a = lols.get(x);
          City b = lols.get(x +1);
          g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
          g.drawLine(a.getX(), a.getY(), b.getX(), b.getY());

       }
```

The error i get:

```
Error:(83, 42) java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from float to int
```

Comment: it seems that X and Y float but drawLine accept ints not float

Answer (score 0):

Java won't let you assign `float`s to `int`s, since, as the error message states, you may lose data there (everything after the decimal point). If you can't change your `x` and `y` values to `int`s (which, off hand, would make the most sense), you can overcome this error by **explicitly** casting your `float`s to `int`s, signifying the potential data loss is intentional, and you're willing to have it:

```
g.drawLine((int) a.getX(), (int) a.getY(), (int) b.getX(), (int) b.getY());
// Here ---^---------------^---------------^---------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

`g.drawLine(...)` method takes four integers. It is evident from the error that `City`'s `getX` and `getY` methods return `float`.

You need to convert these `float`s to `int`s in some consistent way, depending on the range of the values in these `float`s. If the range matches that expected by `drawLine`, you can cast them to `int`:

```
g.drawLine((int)a.getX(), (int)a.getY(), (int)b.getX(), (int)b.getY());
```

If the numbers do not translate well, for example, because `getX` and `getY` return numbers in the range -100..100, and you want to draw them on the 800 by 600 canvas, add method for scaling and/or translating `float` to `int`, for example

```
private static int translateX(float x) {
    // converting from range -100..100 to 0..800
    return (int)(4*(x+100));
}
...
g.drawLine(translateX(a.getX()), translateY(a.getY()), translateX(b.getX()), translateX(b.getY()));
```